# NextJS: Main and Nextscript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Exploring NextJS a bit for its server side rendering features. It looks really nice and easy to use. I already explored the `_document.js` file which we can include to overwrite the default. I found the following code in an example:

```
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <html>
        <Head>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/style.css" />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    )
  }
}
```

Now I get it that we are overwriting the current `HTML` template. But I'm a bit confused regarding the functionality of the `Main` and `Nextscript`.

Is `Main` just a page? What is `Nextscript` (which script)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

NextScript Class is [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/015b0a9d22877218f680642f2f5fec5452eb77ae/server/document.js)

and Main Class is [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/015b0a9d22877218f680642f2f5fec5452eb77ae/server/document.js#L121) and I copied the same below. Main renders html/ errorHtml from `this.context._documentProps`

```
export class Main extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    _documentProps: PropTypes.any
  }

  render () {
    const { html, errorHtml } = this.context._documentProps
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div id='__next' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />
        <div id='__next-error' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: errorHtml }} />
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

you can find actual documentation on Custom Document [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document)

Answer (score 10):

For those who will look for an answer to this question in the future...

Component NextScript from 'next/document' takes a list of files from context._documentProps and returns each of them as a  element like this:

```js
<script
  key={file}
  src={`${assetPrefix}/_next/${file}`}
  nonce={this.props.nonce}
  async
/>
```

It also takes dynamic imports from context._documentProps and returns them in a similar way:

```js
<script
  async
  key={bundle.file}
  src={`${assetPrefix}/_next/${bundle.file}`}
  nonce={this.props.nonce}
/>
```